# How to save generated QRCODE in static/img folder in FLASK

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have the code below that generates a QR code on the user registration and I would like to save it in the static/img folder in order to use it as the user default profile image as I don't seem to be able to load it from the root folder (this is where it currently saves it)

```
@auth.route("/register", methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get("email")
        username = request.form.get("username")
        firstname = request.form.get("firstname")
        lastname = request.form.get("lastname")
        phone = request.form.get("phone")
        password1 = request.form.get("password1")
        password2 = request.form.get("password2")
        
        email_exists = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        phone_exists = User.query.filter_by(phone=phone).first()
        user_exists = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        
        if email_exists:
            flash('Email is already in use', category='error')
        elif user_exists:
            flash('User name is already in use', category='error')    
        elif phone_exists:
            flash('Phone number is already in use', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords don\'t match!', category='error')
        elif len(username) < 1:
            flash('User name needs to be longer than 1 character', category='error')
        elif len(firstname) < 1:
            flash('First name needs to be longer than 1 character', category='error')
        elif len(lastname) < 1:
            flash('Last name needs to be longer than 1 character', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 6:
            flash('Password needs to be longer than 6 character', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email is not valid', category='error')
        else:
            qr = qrcode.make(username)
            type(qr)
            qr.save("{}.png".format(username))
            new_user = User(email=email,username=username, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname, phone=phone, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add (new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(new_user, remember=True)
            flash('User created!',category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
        
    return render_template("register.html", user=current_user)
```

Is there any way to retrieve the image dynamically by using the  or any way to store it in the correct path in order to use